How should I restore stucco on a delaminating retaining wall?
Twenty years ago I built a 3 foot high retaining wall out of cinder blocks, and installed decent "back side" drainage. Well, the drainage is not working, and about 7 years ago the stucco was failing and I had it restuccoed, and the painted with elastomeric paint to match my house.  But the stucco and paint are bubbling and falling off again.  So, I need to fix the surface.  Here is my plan, but I have no confidence that this will work, so I'm looking for experienced advice.

Get as much paint and old stucco off as possible.  I guess demolition chisel, sandblast or pressure washing?
Coat with DryLok Extreme.
Install a wire lath to the cinder block
Put on a scratch coat and a brown coat of waterproof mortar
Put on a thin trowel-on stucco coat
6  Dry and use elastomeric paint.

Any hints or critic would be helpful!  Oh, btw, its about a total of 500 square feet.
It may not be needed for this question, but I will cap with preform concrete cap.

Step 0: Fix drainage.

How big is the wall? For all that effort you could maybe just replace the masonry with rock-face block and call it done.

Well, the wall is about 3-4 foot tall, but its integrated into a rather fancy (for me) grand stairway, so the wall is pretty central to the look of my front.  Plus, my HOA is really picky on wall surfaces.  So I am kina stuck fixing the existing wall.  But thanks for the idea!!

As already stated: step 0: fix drainage (if you had done that last time the surface would likely still be fine)
